# collecting rational, non-symbolic coefficients in SymPy

Tags: sympy

If I have an expression like the following `2 * a + 2 * b + 1`, is there a way to effectively factor out the 2 without substituting it for a symbol?

Edit: My own answer below does not seem to work for rational coefficients, e.g., `collect(a / 2 + b / 2 + 1, Rational(1, 2))` returns `a / 2 + b / 2 + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `collect_const`.

```
a, b = symbols('a b')
test = 2 * a + 2 * b + 1
collect_const(test, 2)
```